# How can I display logs for models served by TensorFlow Serving using GRPC?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, mlops

I am using TensorFlow Serving and the GRPC pattern for serving models. However, I have encountered problems in displaying logs for the served models. While I've successfully used the env var `TF_CPP_VMODULE` to control verbosity for REST endpoints, this approach seems ineffective for gRPC.

I am seeking guidance on effective methods to showcase logs for models served by TensorFlow Serving using the GRPC pattern.